# Prove that $T,S$ are simultaneously diagonalizable iff $TS=ST$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, transformation

**Definition:** We say that $S,T$ are simultaneously diagonalizable if there's a basis, $B$ which composed by eigen-vectores of both $T$ and $S$

> Show that $S,T$ are simultaneously diagonalizable iff $ST=TS$.

I tried both directions, but couldn't get much further.

I'd be glad for help.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you attempted so far, in either direction?

Comment: You should try [searching the site first](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=simultaneously+diagonalizable), as a matter of course

Comment: Please, use the search engine next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint:** If $S = P^{-1} D_S P$ and $T = P^{-1} D_T P$ with $D_{S,T}$ diagonal
then what are the values of $ST$ and $TS$?

Answer (score 5):

"If" is not true. A counterexample is $S=({}^{0\;1}_{0\;0})$ and $T=({}^{1\;0}_{0\;1})$. They trivially commute, but $S$ is not diagonalizable at all, and so in particular not simultaneously with $T$.

Comment: Cute matrices. ${}$